# FTP - skipping already sent files

Tags: scripting, ftp, cron

Is there an easy way to automate a process so that if I want a script (.sh) to run hourly, it can check what files have already been FTPed and skip those and only send new ones?  Thanks

Here is my current feed. I am not sure how rsync would be configured...

```
/usr/local/bin/ncftpput -f saxlogin.cfg /MTM/PH /mnt/zeus/scripts/xml/pph/date +"%Y.%m.%d"/*
```

Comment: Can you use rsync instead of FTP?

Comment: Edit your question, don't try to put code in comments.

Comment: What about storing them in a file and keep checking the list?